# Can I override ARIA role on the details-summary element?

Tags: html, wai-aria

So, I'm wrapping heading tags (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) in `<details>` and `<summary>`.  The problem is they lose the "heading" ARIA role by default.  From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary):

> Warning: Because the  element has a default role of button (which strips all roles from child elements), this example will not work for users of assistive technologies such as screen readers. The  will have its role removed and thus will not be treated as a heading for these users.

But can't you easily fix this by overriding as below? The reason I ask is that I haven't seen this trick anywhere in my Googling, just lots of complaints about how the details-summary elements are broken and unfixable.  So maybe I am missing something.

```
<details>
  <summary role="heading" aria-level="2"><h2>Heading</h2></summary>
  Lorem ipsum...
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

The <details>/<summary> element is a good *semantic* element which gives you some "free" built in accessibility but it does have limitations, as you noticed.

The <summary> is essentially a <button aria-expanded="false">.  It's a button that has the [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-expanded) attribute.  If you override the role of the <summary>, then it will no longer announce as a button, which means the screen reader user might not know that it's an interactive element.

Hearing "heading" on the <summary> would be a little confusing especially since the intrinsic `aria-expanded` is still announced. Screen reader users wouldn't expect a heading to be expandable/collapsable since a heading should not be an interactive element.

It's not advised to override the default native semantics of an element. That is, if an element has a default [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions), don't override that role.

The [second rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#secondrule) says:

> Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to.

An interesting side note is that the "[content model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-summary-element:concept-element-content-model)" of the <summary> element says that headings **can** be used inside it.

> **Content Model:** Phrasing content, *optionally intermixed with heading content.*

So technically you should be able to have headings inside a <summary> but it's not supported consistently. NVDA (PC screen reader) **will** announce a heading embedded in a <summary>.  It will also announce a <table> embedded in a <summary>, although I'd strongly discourage that.  JAWS (another PC screen reader) will **not** announce a heading (or a table) embedded in a <summary>. I suppose that's a JAWS bug since, as noted above, a <summary> is allowed to have headings.

In summary (no pun intended), I would not advise putting headings, or any other semantic html elements, inside a <summary> element. I don't know how your page is organized but a possible alternative is having the heading *outside*/*before* the <details>/<summary>.

```html
<h2>important stuff here</h2>
<details>
  <summary>normal text</summary>
  lorem ipsum
</details>
```

Comment: From your description, this ARIA override sounds kind of correct. If I was the one visiting my own site with a screen reader, I would instantly get what it would mean for a heading to be "expanded".  Example page: https://edstrom.dev/zt26KxP/nutrition (still working on a visual indication).  But I've worked with this paradigm for so many years that I can't guess how intuitive it is to people who haven't.  Anyway, I'm trying to figure out an alternative.  Maybe I can have a blank <summary> after a heading, so it's just a clickable arrow -- or would a blank <summary> be poor accessibility too?

Comment: Depending on how tech-savvy the screen reader user is, they *might* be able to hear "expanded" on a heading and figure out they could "collapse" it, but it would be strange to hear an interactive state (expanded/collapsed) on an non-interactive element (heading). I would avoid overriding the role of the <summary> because I think it makes for a *worse* accessibility experience, and, as noted above, the 2nd rule of ARIA says to not override the default role.

Comment: As far as a blank <summary>, the screen reader would say "button collapsed" so the user would hear there's a button and that it's collapsed, but the button would not have a name. That would violate [WCAG 4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value)